# How to correctly use this filter in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, twitter

I'm working with [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-tweets-widget/) Twitter plugin. I output it's content by using the `do_shortcode` function within my template.

Within their [other notes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-tweets-widget/other_notes/) section, it says I can override the custom HTML markup that it will output the tweets within a list object by using `add_filter('latest_tweets_render_list')`

However, when I do

```
add_filter('latest_tweets_render_list', function( array $list ){
 return '<div>'.$list.'</div>';
}, 10, 1);
```

I get a PHP warning stating that there is an `array to string conversion` and it outputs no tweets.

I took a look in the plugins core files and there is this.

```
function latest_tweets_render_html( $screen_name = '', $num = 5, $rts = true, $ats = true, $pop = 0 ){
    $items = latest_tweets_render( $screen_name, $num, $rts, $ats, $pop );
    $list  = apply_filters('latest_tweets_render_list', $items, $screen_name );
    if( is_array($list) ){
        $list = '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>',$items).'</li></ul>';
    }
    return 
        '<div class="latest-tweets">'. 
            apply_filters( 'latest_tweets_render_before', '' ).
            $list.
            apply_filters( 'latest_tweets_render_after', '' ).
        '</div>';
}
```

How do I correctly use the `latest_tweet_render_list` filter in order to override the default HTML markup? I have tried to use a foreach loop but that didn't do the trick either. I do not wish to modify the plugin files if it's avoidable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback method is passed an `array` - you can't simply output an array (hence your message about the conversion). Depending on what is in the array, you can do something like this:

```
add_filter('latest_tweets_render_list', function( array $list ){
  $output = '<div>';
  foreach ($list as $l) {
    $output .= $l;
  }
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}, 10, 1);
```

To see the items in your `$list` variable, you can use `var_dump($list)` at the top of your function first.

Comment: I did mention that I tried a foreach loop but my markup was slightly incorrect, thanks.

Comment: Ah yeah I forgot to mention that it ought to work :) no worries